# Is a brightness control widget available?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, indicator, brightness, gnome-classic

Is it possible to place a slider or some other GUI component on the desktop / Notification Panel on Ubuntu 12.04 to control the screen brightness?

It's a little annoying to constantly have to go to the system settings to turn the brightness down.

Comment: Anything is possible.  Are you asking for someone to write a widget that does that?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to control the brightness from the panel or desktop like there was in the old gnome. It's not fun to have to dig through system settings everytime you need to change the brightness.

Comment: inadition... the HomePage: https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ppa
more info and configurations: http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a brightness indicator app that looks like:

[image]

And can be downloaded from [here](http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128) (although it has 11.04 and 11.10 versions, it is said to work with 12.04 also).

The indicator is written in python and the source-code can be [found here](http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/filedownload/download.php/?path=http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/indicator-brightness-maxsteps.py&type=text/plain&referer=/wordpress/?p=128).

Comment: Good answer. Didn't work with my installation though.